# stick my control to skype window control

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, c++builder, skype

I'm creating a skype tool with C++ Builder.
I want to stick/add my button to skype window TChatRichEdit.
I'm not sure how to do it in the proper way.

Also I have TSkype object on the form, maybe it is possible to use it to attach my button to skype window. I would like to attach it to different window zones like under TConversationForm, or under TContactProfile.

How to do that ?
other skype tool can do that.

Comment: This sort of question gets asked quite often. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298708/missing-functionality-of-added-control-in-another-application  Don't expect any joy in this. Trying to put a window from one process into the window of another leads to pain and suffering. Find a different way to solve your problem.

Comment: There's no proper way.

Comment: May be this helps: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA214/what-is-the-desktop-api